# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null - JS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, styles, document

I'm getting a javascript error from my console that reads:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Code (JS):

```
<script>
    function select()
    {
        document.getElementById('#iframetest').style.display='block';
    }

</script>
```

Code (HTML):

```
<iframe src="localhost/createaclass" id="iframetest"></iframe>

<div class="b" onclick="select()">
```

Comment: there is no jQuery used in this code...

Comment: the `#` is used to specify a id selector, but `document.getElementById()` does not accept a selector, it expects an id to be passed to it

Answer (score 9):

Don't place the hash in id (#):

```
document.getElementById('iframetest')
```

As per your comment, you can do like this:

```
function select()
{
   document.getElementById('iframetest').style.display = 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Comment: I would like the element to be hidden and show on click, however the element shows anyway. Any suggestions? :) Thank you by the way

Comment: @user3818791 For that you can say `<iframe src="localhost/createaclass" id="iframetest" style="display:none"></iframe>`

Comment: I've already stated within my framework, it still shows regardless

Comment: there should be `document.getElementById('iframetest').style.display == 'block'` , fix that. you are assigning.

Comment: #iframetest
{
 display:none;
}That is my CSS but its still automatically showing.

Answer (score 2):

Move your JS below the HTML.

```
<iframe src="localhost/createaclass" id="iframetest"></iframe>
<div class="b" onclick="select()">

<script>
  function select()
  {
    document.getElementById('#iframetest').style.display='block';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late to answer it. But your selector is returning null because at this line

```
document.getElementById('#iframetest').style.display='block';
```

You need to change it to:

```
document.getElementById('iframetest').style.display='block';
```

When you specify getElementById, then your JS will directly go to the element with the id of 'iframetest'. There is no need of '#'.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using jquery. it's working.

```
$('.b').click(function(){
$('#iframetest').hide();
});


<iframe src="localhost/createaclass" id="iframetest"></iframe>
<div class="b">selectDiv</div>
```

see jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/17duuxcm/5/